# how to check, checkbox is check or not in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

```
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn GvCheckBox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        doWork.HeaderText = "Approved Cheque";
        doWork.FalseValue = "0";
        doWork.TrueValue = "1";
GvViewPendingCheque.Columns.Insert(0, doWork);
        GvViewPendingCheque.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables[0];
```

its working fine checkbox column has been added in grid with db data,
i want to update data of all row where checkbox is check

MyTable Column: PaymentStatus
MyTable Data:   Pending

when admin check,checkbox PaymentStatus will update with Approved istead of Pending
please help me,
i have try this code but its not working:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GvViewPendingCheque.Rows)
                    {

                        if ((bool)row.Cells[doWork.Name].Value == true)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("True");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed...");
                        }
                    }
```

and

```
if ((bool)this.GvViewPendingCheque.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("True");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("False");
            }
```

just want to know how to get checkbox 'check' rows

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: are you sure that `GvViewPendingCheque.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` is correct? are you just checking the first row?

Comment: when i check,checkbox,and click button,Error Occur:Specified cast is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

```
 if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.GvViewPendingCheque.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        ...
```

but i'm nut sure if this is a correct way to access a cell in your data grid view.
easier way to access a cell [row, column]:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.GvViewPendingCheque[0,0].Value) == true)
```

Comment: Error:string was not recognize as a valid boolean

Comment: I think that the definition of true and false values are wrong, it should be booleans, 0 or 1, istead of "0" and "1"

Comment: its now working,i am using 2nd answer,but i have 3 records in db,when i check,checkbox messagebox prompt 4 time with true where 1 have only select 1 checkbox ' foreach (DataGridViewRow GvRow in GvViewPendingCheque.Rows)
            {
        
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.GvViewPendingCheque[0, 0].Value) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("True");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("False");
                }
            }'

Comment: that's because you're doing a loop on each row, but inside the loop you're accessing only the first row! change the parameter of ToBoolean to:  GvRow.Cells[0].Value

Comment: If (Convert.ToBoolean(GvRow.Cells[0].Value) == true). Hope helps

Comment: Great Its Work,need little bit help more, can u tell me how to get selected checkbox row column value? basically i want to update records of checkbox selected example: PaymentStatus:Pending to Approved

Comment: Id like to help yku more but sounds it has no connection to that issue. Im sure youre question has a solution in Stackoverflow, try to google it or post a new question. Mark as answeed if helped bud :)

Comment: i can't start new question now,90 minutes validation :( help me if u can

Comment: If (Convert.ToBoolean(GvRow.Cells[0].Value) == true) GvRow.Cells[columnIndexToUpdate].Value = "Approved"; else GvRow.Cells[columnIndexToUpdate].Value = "Pending";   ColumnIndexToUpdate is the column index you want to insert the info as Integer

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the false and true values to "0" and "1", respectively. But converting strings to boolean like you're attempting to do in the `foreach` loop will throw a `FormatException`.

Converting the numbers 0 and 1 to booleans, on the other hand, will return `false` and `true`.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn GvCheckBox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

GvCheckBox.FalseValue = 0;  // replaced "0"
GvCheckBox.TrueValue = 1;   // replaced "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your cell into a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell then you should be able to use the checked property to see if checked

```
cell1.checked == true
```